# How to correctly use MPI.Allgather() in python to gather different sized arrays from different processes

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I'm using mpi4py currently, and I have a bunch of processes that are generating lists of tuples (or numpy arrays of tuples). At the end of each process, I want to call an allgather so that each process gets every list (Ideally, they are concatenated).

Unfortunately, the documentation on the mpi4py page doesn't cover allgather(), so I was wondering if anyone could help me. I'm confused if I'd need to use allgather() or allgatherv() or Allgather(), and essentially how this would work since I'm not scattering any data before-hand.

Comment: Although scatter and gather are complementary operations and often used in tandem, nothing prevents you from using each of them alone to achieve data distribution or gathering. (All)gather simply takes smaller pieces of data stored locally in each rank and concatenates them into a larger piece. For pieces of varying size, you need `Allgatherv()`. Since it needs to know the data size in each rank, you need to first `Allgather()` the array lengths.

Comment: GitHub is a good way to find examples of how things work. Searching for `comm.Allgatherv` in Python code yields a lot of result. Here is [one of them](https://github.com/andrthu/master/blob/96ee40ad9a017d02ed9fb51e28ce47448f847172/adjoint/my_bfgs/mpiVector.py#L108).